# Error while switching to php-5.5.17 with laragon

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php

I am trying to configure php-5.5.17 downloaded from https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.17.tar.bz2

unzipped in laragon/bin/php and switched from laragon menu to php-5.5.17.

Getting this error:

```
Service Apache can not start. Reason: 
----------------------------------------
AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of C:/laragon/etc/apache2/fcgid.conf:
Wrapper C:/laragon/bin/php/php-5.5.17/php-cgi.exe cannot be accessed: (720002)The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the on-disk folder structure is correct?

Comment: @DanielB above image added for folder structure?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you downloaded the source code. You need a binary distribution that’s suitable for your use case.

Comment: @DanielB yeh that error passed as per new binary downloaded. but now the error is: Your PHP Version (php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x64)
& Apache Version (httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16)
are not compatible! 
Please make sure PHP and Apache are both:
- x86 (win32) or x64 (win64)
- Same VC (VC11, VC14, VC15...)

Comment: Tried using httpd-2.2.34-win64 also same error

Comment: Solved: 

For my php version: php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x64 i tried to find and downloaded : httpd-2.4.38-win64-VC11 from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/#google_vignette solved the issue.

Comment: Great to hear you solved your problem! Instead of just reporting this in a comment here, add an answer below. Don’t forget to accept it, too, after the cooldown timer passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: For my php version: `php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x64` I tried to find and downloaded : `httpd-2.4.38-win64-VC11` from `apachelounge.com/download/VC11/#google_vignettez` solved the issue.

Note: PHP need to be downloaded as binary not source code. from: `https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/`

Also, if needed then install the `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4` as per compatible in your machine.